# Cannot seem to change the color of a button

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of my 'check out' button to orange in my cart page.

I have tried the following:

```
<button type="submit" style="width: 100%" name="checkout" class="btn" 
style="background-color:#FFA500">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</button>
```

However, the color remains blue (which is the overal color theme of my website).

Does anyone see an error in the above html code or would have a clue why the above color code is overriden?

BTW, I have managed to change other buttons on other pages of my website using the abovec code.

Many thanks.

Best regads,

Answer (score 4):

You can define `style` attribute only once in your `html` and add as many `CSS` properties in that `style` attribute as you want

```
<button type="submit" style="width: 100%; background-color:#FFA500" 
        name="checkout" class="btn">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put all the styles in several attributes.
Put all the css properties of element into one style tag separated by ";":

```
 style="width: 100%; background-color:#FFA500"
```

Of course would not recommend to do it inline (inside html tag), but to assign CSS properties  to a id (unique) or class (same type of elements) in .css file which should be included in head tag 
HTML:

```
<button type="submit" style="width: 100%;background-color:#FFA500" name="checkout" class="btn checkout">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</button>
```

CSS (styles.css) :

```
.checkout{
width: 100%;
background-color:#FFA500;
}
```